# Endpoint using Akka Http and Circe, payload entity and default values of case class

Tags: scala, serialization, deserialization, akka-http, circe

Implementing Rest API services with Scala I'm using Akka Http v10.2.3 and Circe v0.13.0.

Let's say I have this endpoint:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._

...

pathPrefix("test") { 
    post {
      entity(as[SomeData]) { data =>
        // do something with the data (instance of SomeData)
        ...
        complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      }
    }
  }
```

And SomeData case class:

```
case class SomeData(someString: String, someInt: Int = 0)
```

If I hit this endpoint with this json:

```
{ "someString": "value", "someInt": 123}
```

Then Circe will store `SomeData(value, 123)` in the variable `data`.

If I hit the endpoint with this json:

```
{ "someString": "value"}
```

Then Circe will fail because `someInt` is missing.

Is there any way with Circe to set the value 0 defined as default in the case class when the payload is `{"someString: "value"}` and `someInt` is missing in the json (without using Option)?

UPDATE:
I'm trying to use `io.circe.generic.extras` but I can't make it work (at this point I created an implicit val in both sources but it doesn't work either) Here is the complete source:

```
package com.defaultValues

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpcirce.FailFastCirceSupport
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure
import SomeData._

object SomeApi extends App with FailFastCirceSupport {
  val serviceName: String          = "default-values"
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem(serviceName)
  import system.dispatcher

  import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
  import io.circe.generic.extras.auto._
  implicit val someDataConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults

  val routes = pathPrefix("default-values") {
    post {
      entity(as[SomeData]) { data =>
        println(s"POST /test, body $data")
        complete(data)
      }
    }
  }

  Http()
    .newServerAt("localhost", 8084)
    .bind(routes)
    .onComplete {
      case Success(_)         => println(s"app started $serviceName")
      case Failure(exception) => println(s"app failed to start $serviceName", exception)
    }
}
```

```
package com.defaultValues

import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.{deriveDecoder, deriveEncoder}

case class SomeData(someString: String, someInt: Int = 0)

object SomeData {
  import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
  implicit val customConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDefaults

  implicit val someDataDecoder: Decoder[SomeData] = deriveDecoder[SomeData]
  implicit val someDataEncoder: Encoder[SomeData] = deriveEncoder[SomeData]
}
```

build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.2"

val akkaVersion          = "2.6.9"
val akkaHttpVersion      = "10.2.0"
val akkaHttpCirceVersion = "1.31.0"
val circeVersion         = "0.13.0"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed"     % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-typed"   % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http"            % akkaHttpVersion,
  "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-circe"      % akkaHttpCirceVersion,
  "io.circe"          %% "circe-core"           % circeVersion,
  "io.circe"          %% "circe-generic"        % circeVersion,
  "io.circe"          %% "circe-parser"         % circeVersion,
  "io.circe"          %% "circe-refined"        % circeVersion,
  "io.circe"          %% "circe-generic-extras" % circeVersion,
)
```

EXAMPLE:
When I send this payload:

```
{ "someString": "value1" }
```

I get:

```
The request content was malformed:
Attempt to decode value on failed cursor: DownField(someInt)
```

Comment: Circe provides configuration option to use defaults
```implicit val customConfig = Configuration.default.withDefaults```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can't not make it work ... First I tried adding the configuration in the companion object, didn't worked. Then I tried adding the configuration in the class that contains the routes and also I didn't worked ... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It has to be in the same scope as `SomeData`. See examples in documentation here (bottom of the page): https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html. You probably also have to use `@ConfiguredJsonCodec` annotation.

Comment: I've updated the description adding all the source including circe.generic.extras ...

Comment: Did you consider making `someInt` optional instead? Then you could have handled the default any way you like, and only right when you need the default value. Circe would have been perfectly happy about it. This allows you to do other things, like log the fact that `someInt` is missing or conditionally set the default to some other value, etc. Setting a default right away when you're trying to parse the request essentially masks what was actually sent in the request, since you no longer know if the user sent that value or if your code replaced it when parsing the object.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

Instead of this:

```
implicit val someDataDecoder: Decoder[SomeData] = deriveDecoder[SomeData]
implicit val someDataEncoder: Encoder[SomeData] = deriveEncoder[SomeData]
```

I had to use this:

```
implicit val someDataDecoder: Decoder[SomeData] = deriveConfiguredDecoder
implicit val someDataEncoder: Encoder[SomeData] = deriveConfiguredEncoder
```

And add this import:

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto.{deriveConfiguredDecoder, deriveConfiguredEncoder}
```